# clojure.java.jdbc/insert - Unable to insert a sequence of vectors dynamically for batch insert into sql

Tags: sql, clojure

I am trying to insert a sequence of vectors as rows in sql using clojure.java.jdbc/insert! function which takes in input as given in :

http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/using_sql.html#inserting-data

I am unable to map over a sequence of vectors like (["a" 1 "c"] ["b" 2 "d"] ["d" 3 "e"]....) dynamically by mapping over it since it uses the following syntax

```
(j/insert! db-spec :fruit
         nil ; column names not supplied
         [1 "Apple" "red" 59 87]
         [2 "Banana" "yellow" 29 92.2]
         [3 "Peach" "fuzzy" 139 90.0]
         [4 "Orange" "juicy" 89 88.6])
```

I want to be able to insert dynamically into sql for batch insert. How can i do this? TIA.

Comment: You are probably looking for apply, i.e. `(apply j/insert! db-spec :fruit nil '([1 "Apple" "red"] [2 "Banana" "yellow"]))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using apply (which will apply your entire list of args as args to the j/insert! function)

```
(def args-list '([1 "Apple" "red" 59 87]
                 [2 "Banana" "yellow" 29 92.2]
                 [3 "Peach" "fuzzy" 139 90.0]
                 [4 "Orange" "juicy" 89 88.6] ...))

(apply j/insert! db-spec :fruit args-list)
```

Comment: I had to use partial inside the function that you've defined to get it to work. Thanks for the help